# Python - How to use soup with random class characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to figure out how to scrape a website for a buy/sell site and I have came to a place where I found everything in a HTML but the class contains different random numbers such as:

```
<div aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape" class="styled__Wrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-0 eDiSuB" to="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">
    <article class="styled__Article-sc-1kpvi4z-1 hbWRzz">
        <div class="styled__ImageWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-4 kxhCJn">
            <div class="ListImage__Wrapper-sc-1rp77jc-0 cvipJS"><img alt="Adidas NMD x Bape" class="ListImage__StyledImg-sc-1rp77jc-1 iwClwW" sizes="
              (min-width: 768px) 180px,
              120px
            " src="https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big" srcset="
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=thumb 120w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big 180w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal 240w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=store_presentation 360w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal_retina 540w,
  " /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="styled__Content-sc-1kpvi4z-2 dwtNsH">
            <div class="styled__LocationTimeWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-17 dvvNDw">
                <div class="styled__SubjectSymbol-sc-1kpvi4z-11 cbBbUz"></div>
                <p class="styled__TopInfoWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-22 kEcJNb"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/hela_sverige/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;st=s">Kläder &amp; skor</a> · <a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/skane/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;r=23&amp;st=s">Skåne</a></p>
                <p class="styled__Time-sc-1kpvi4z-18 bGSnhf">Idag 14:06</p>
            </div>
            <div class="styled__SubjectWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-10 kZyTSM">
                <h2 class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq styled__StyledTitle-sc-1kpvi4z-6 bSElwy"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 styled__StyledTitleLink-sc-1kpvi4z-7 edlhAW" href="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">Adidas NMD x Bape</a></h2></div>
            <div class="styled__ParamsWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-13 cRZIFG"></div>
            <div class="styled__SalesInfo-sc-1kpvi4z-20 bbHjGJ">
                <div class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq Price__Wrapper-sc-1v2maoc-0 heunWX"><span>3 000 kr<div class="TextCallout2__TextCallout2Wrapper-sc-19qvftl-0 eERYUj Price__StyledVatPrice-sc-1v2maoc-1 hMWxAJ"></div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

I do see all the tags I am looking for such as:

```
    Adidas NMD x Bape
    3 000 kr
    Skåne
    /annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg
```

I do have a quite knowledge about soup and how to scrape basic but when it come to this advanced then I am out of my mind so I am here asking what kind of tip you guys can provide me on how I can be able to scrape those values I am looking for?

---

updated

```
test = eachPart.select_one('h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a').text
print(test)
print(eachPart.select_one('[aria-label="{}"] img[alt="{}"]'.format(test, test))['src'])
print(eachPart.select_one('h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a')['href'])
print(eachPart.select_one('div[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >span').text)
for test in eachPart.select('p[class^="styled__TopInfoWrapper"] a')[1:]:
    print(test.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the Parent tag  first to find the main tag and then find all child tag.
Use **CSS** selector which is more convenient.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape" caria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"lass="styled__Wrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-0 eDiSuB" to="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">
    <article class="styled__Article-sc-1kpvi4z-1 hbWRzz">
        <div class="styled__ImageWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-4 kxhCJn">
            <div class="ListImage__Wrapper-sc-1rp77jc-0 cvipJS"><img alt="Adidas NMD x Bape" class="ListImage__StyledImg-sc-1rp77jc-1 iwClwW" sizes="
              (min-width: 768px) 180px,
              120px
            " src="https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big" srcset="
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=thumb 120w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big 180w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal 240w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=store_presentation 360w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal_retina 540w,
  " /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="styled__Content-sc-1kpvi4z-2 dwtNsH">
            <div class="styled__LocationTimeWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-17 dvvNDw">
                <div class="styled__SubjectSymbol-sc-1kpvi4z-11 cbBbUz"></div>
                <p class="styled__TopInfoWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-22 kEcJNb"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/hela_sverige/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;st=s">Kläder &amp; skor</a> · <a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/skane/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;r=23&amp;st=s">Skåne</a></p>
                <p class="styled__Time-sc-1kpvi4z-18 bGSnhf">Idag 14:06</p>
            </div>
            <div class="styled__SubjectWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-10 kZyTSM">
                <h2 class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq styled__StyledTitle-sc-1kpvi4z-6 bSElwy"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 styled__StyledTitleLink-sc-1kpvi4z-7 edlhAW" href="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">Adidas NMD x Bape</a></h2></div>
            <div class="styled__ParamsWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-13 cRZIFG"></div>
            <div class="styled__SalesInfo-sc-1kpvi4z-20 bbHjGJ">
                <div class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq Price__Wrapper-sc-1v2maoc-0 heunWX"><span>3 000 kr<div class="TextCallout2__TextCallout2Wrapper-sc-19qvftl-0 eERYUj Price__StyledVatPrice-sc-1v2maoc-1 hMWxAJ"></div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('[aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"] img[alt="Adidas NMD x Bape"]')['src'])
print(soup.select_one('[aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"] h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a').text)
print(soup.select_one('[aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"] h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a')['href'])
print(soup.select_one('[aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"] div[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >span').text)
```

**Output**:

```
https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big
Adidas NMD x Bape
/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675
3 000 kr
```

**EDIT**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape" class="styled__Wrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-0 eDiSuB" to="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">
    <article class="styled__Article-sc-1kpvi4z-1 hbWRzz">
        <div class="styled__ImageWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-4 kxhCJn">
            <div class="ListImage__Wrapper-sc-1rp77jc-0 cvipJS"><img alt="Adidas NMD x Bape" class="ListImage__StyledImg-sc-1rp77jc-1 iwClwW" sizes="
              (min-width: 768px) 180px,
              120px
            " src="https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big" srcset="
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=thumb 120w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=gallery_big 180w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal 240w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=store_presentation 360w,
    https://cdn.blocket.com/pictures/1692451915.jpg?type=mob_iphone_vi_normal_retina 540w,
  " /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="styled__Content-sc-1kpvi4z-2 dwtNsH">
            <div class="styled__LocationTimeWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-17 dvvNDw">
                <div class="styled__SubjectSymbol-sc-1kpvi4z-11 cbBbUz"></div>
                <p class="styled__TopInfoWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-22 kEcJNb"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/hela_sverige/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;st=s">Kläder &amp; skor</a> · <a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 TopInfoLink__StyledLink-lzfj8j-0 bjnLor" href="/annonser/skane/personligt/klader_skor?cg=4080&amp;q=bape&amp;r=23&amp;st=s">Skåne</a></p>
                <p class="styled__Time-sc-1kpvi4z-18 bGSnhf">Idag 14:06</p>
            </div>
            <div class="styled__SubjectWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-10 kZyTSM">
                <h2 class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq styled__StyledTitle-sc-1kpvi4z-6 bSElwy"><a class="Link-sc-139ww1j-0 styled__StyledTitleLink-sc-1kpvi4z-7 edlhAW" href="/annons/skane/adidas_nmd_x_bape/87267675">Adidas NMD x Bape</a></h2></div>
            <div class="styled__ParamsWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-13 cRZIFG"></div>
            <div class="styled__SalesInfo-sc-1kpvi4z-20 bbHjGJ">
                <div class="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper-sc-1ilszdp-0 jIvScq Price__Wrapper-sc-1v2maoc-0 heunWX"><span>3 000 kr<div class="TextCallout2__TextCallout2Wrapper-sc-19qvftl-0 eERYUj Price__StyledVatPrice-sc-1v2maoc-1 hMWxAJ"></div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('[class^="styled__Wrapper-sc-"] img[class^="ListImage__StyledImg-sc-"]')['src'])
print(soup.select_one('[class^="styled__Wrapper-sc-"] h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a').text)
print(soup.select_one('[class^="styled__Wrapper-sc-"] h2[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >a')['href'])
print(soup.select_one('[class^="styled__Wrapper-sc-"] div[class^="TextSubHeading__TextSubHeadingWrapper"] >span').text)
```

Comment: Hello! Hmm, What about if `aria-label` has random name for every link etc? In that case you are not able to "hardcode" the aria-label `[aria-label="Adidas NMD x Bape"]` but what could be good is to be able to actually scrape the `[aria-label` value instead of hardcoding it like you, how would you able to do that?

Comment: I edited my question with the code I am using. It seems to work but I am not sure if this is correct way to do it?

Comment: You can do that.However You can use the parent tag class startswith instead of aria-label like I did h2 class startswith.

Comment: Ohhh you are a live saver! Could you just provide me an example of the code you meant with startswith? Also once again, thanks for everything!

Comment: @Thrillofit86 :Check Edited Answer.

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be lot better. I added a section where you missed but I solved it with a foor loop, not sure if there is another way around. Its in row `<p class="styled__TopInfoWrapper-sc-1kpvi4z-22 kEcJNb">` at the end of the whole row where it says `Skåne`

Comment: Yes I missed it.I didn’t check that you have added that value as well.If this resolve your problem please don’t hesitate to mark it accepted.Thanks